# How to toggle Bold or Italic if a cell is in edit mode?

Tags: excel, vba

```
If Selection.Font.Bold = False Then
Selection.Font.Bold = True
Else
Selection.Font.Bold = False
End If
```

This works if a range is selected.
How to create the same if a cell is in edit mode, and only a part of its content is selected ?

Comment: You can't run a macro when a cell is in edit mode.  If you want to bold or italic only part of a cell's content then you'd need to do that after the edit is completed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you would use to format parts of a cell, but you can only do this after the edit is complete - like Tim Williams said.

```
With ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=3, Length:=2).Font
    .Name = "Calibri"
    .Size = 11
    .Strikethrough = False
    .Superscript = False
    .Subscript = False
    .OutlineFont = False
    .Shadow = False
    .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
End With
```

Comment: Jook, but Selection can have various Start and Length. Is it then possible to define Start and Length of a selection in edit mode ?

Comment: I do not know of any "default/ment-to-be" way to access a cell during edit mode. There is no event defined for that to catch on eigther. `Start:=3` and `Length:=2` are used to select your already given and fixed characters. The behaviour is different when you use excel as a user, because then you're out of the VBA-Scope ;) There might be a way to hack in to that, but this would be rather a hack, then specified behaviour.